# Apache Ignite Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: java, xml, maven, ignite

I have just created simple Java project, it works fine when I run the from intellji, however when I convert to the jar file and run, gives me error like this: (when i remove  Property 'includeEventTypes, it works fine with jar!!)

```
Bean 'ignite.cfg'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/util]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:.../JarIgnite/target/JarIgnite-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/config.xml]
Bean 'ignite.cfg'
        -> Property 'includeEventTypes']
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:744)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:945)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:854)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:724)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:693)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:352)
        ... 2 more
```

There is no validation error in `pom.xml` and `config.xml`,

Here is `pom.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">                  
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.JarIgnite</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarIgnite</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-executable-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                    <mainClass>default_package.MainApp</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Here is the config.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enable task execvcution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list >
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="gridLogger">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
                <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="/home/nova-stats/Desktop/log/ignite-log4j.xml"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I think there's some problem with your `jar-with-dependencies`. You need [spring-beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254417/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-util) and it should be referenced by ignite-spring normally.

Comment: @alamar, I can not solve the way that you provided via link, more interestingly, it will works, when i write configuration programmatically way, not an xml.

Comment: A quick google search shows this a bug in maven-assemble-plugin and SO already has a post on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335203/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335203/unable-to-locate-spring-namespacehandler-error)

Answer (score 0):

Add next dependencies (you must follow specified order!)

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ignite/ignite-spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```